# Сумма двух массивов

Tags: java, массивы

Есть матрица 100х100 и массив из ста элементов. Нужно просуммировать массив и и каждый ряд матрицы и записать это в отдельный массив. 
Это возможно???

```
public class Distance {

    public static int[] distance(int[] etalonMatrix, int[][] convertToMatrix){

        int[] etalon = etalonMatrix;
        int [][] matrix = convertToMatrix;
        int [] distance = new int[80];


    }

}
```

Вот попыталась это все нарисовать, но рисую я плохо(
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: да, возможно, дополните кодом матрицы и укажите, что у Вас не получается.

Comment: @Даша Новикова  Может быть вы ошиблись с описанием вашего задания? Более естественно описание выглядело бы следующим образом. Есть матрица и есть массив. Нужно суммы элементов матрицы по строкам занести в массив. Или вы имеете в виду, что элементы каждого ряда матрицы суммируются с элементами массива?

Comment: Очень похоже на учебное задание, которое автор не хочет решать сам.

Comment: @MrFylypenko правила

Comment: @VladfromMoscow правила

Comment: @ДашаНовикова Если рисуете плохо, то не быть вам программистом. Лучше подавайтесь в художники! Там вы будете пользоваться успехом как постмодернист.:)

Comment: Попробуйте освоить какой-нибудь векторный редактор, иллюстрации сразу станут ровнее и, наверное, красивее. Например, [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/).

Comment: хМ. В итоге получается формула `z(i) = 100y(i)+Σx(i)(j)`. Совершенно незачем складывать `y` сто раз

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(int x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
        for(int y = 0; y < 100; y++) {
            distance[x] += etalon[x] + matrix[x][y];
        }
    }

return distance;
```

Comment: Разобрался, все верно, только после 1 цикла нужно обнулять distace